# Random line using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to select a random line with `sed`.  I know `shuf -n` and `sort -R | head -n` does the job, but for `shuf` you have to install `coreutils`, and for the `sort solution`, it isn't optimal on large data :

Here is what I tested :

```
echo "$var" | shuf -n1
```

Which gives the optimal solution but I'm afraid for portability
that's why I want to try it with `sed`.

```
`var="Hi
 i am a student
 learning scripts"`

output:
i am a student

output:
hi
```

It must be Random.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Thank yeah no problem i will edit

Comment: Is the number of lines known?

Comment: doing this with bash and sed would be even less efficient, what's wrong with installing coreutils?

Comment: Why do you need to use sed specifically? There are lots of tools available on just about every system that might be a better fit.

Comment: @Cyrus  Yeah i can get the number of lines

Comment: @Caleb not necessarly i just wanted to see how it would go with sed but if you could point me on those tools i'll be more than happy

Comment: `seq 10 | sed "$(( RANDOM % N + 1 ))! d"`, where `N=10` i.e. number of input lines

Comment: sed and awk are both standard UNIX tools and sed has no capability for generating random numbers while awk has a function named `rand()` to do just that. So why do you feel like you need a sed instead of an awk solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends greatly on what you want your pseudo-random probability distribution to look like.  (Don't try for random, be content with pseudo-random.  If you do manage to generate a truly random value, go collect your nobel prize.)  If you just want a uniform distribution (eg, each line has equal probability of being selected), then you'll need to know a priori how many lines of are in the file.  Getting that distribution is not quite so easy as allowing the earlier lines in the file to be slightly more likely to be selected, and since that's easy, we'll do that.  Assuming that the number of lines is less than 32769, you can simply do:

```
N=$(wc -l < input-file)
sed -n -e $((RANDOM % N + 1))p input-file
```

-- edit --

After thinking about it for a bit, I realize you don't need to know the number of lines, so you don't need to read the data twice.  I haven't done a rigorous analysis, but I believe that the following gives a uniform distribution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()} rand() < 1/NR { out=$0 } END { print out }' input-file
```

-- edit --
Ed Morton suggests in the comments that we should be able to invoke rand() only once.  That seems like it ought to work, but doesn't seem to.  Curious:

```
$ time for i in $(seq 400); do awk -v seed=$(( $(date +%s) + i)) 'BEGIN{srand(seed); r=rand()} r < 1/NR { out=$0 } END { print out}'  input; done | awk '{a[$0]++} END { for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' | sort
1 205
2 64
3 37
4 21
5 9
6 9
7 9
8 46

real    0m1.862s
user    0m0.689s
sys     0m0.907s
$ time for i in $(seq 400); do awk -v seed=$(( $(date +%s) + i)) 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} rand() < 1/NR { out=$0 } END { print out}'  input; done | awk '{a[$0]++} END { for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' | sort
1 55
2 60
3 37
4 50
5 57
6 45
7 50
8 46

real    0m1.924s
user    0m0.710s
sys     0m0.932s
```

Comment: I like the awk solution and I agree, it seems like it should work but couldn't you just call `rand()` once in the BEGIN section and use a variable instead of calling it once per line of input? Since srand() by default seeds with the current seconds since epoch value it'll produce the same output if you run it twice within 1 sec - if you care you could change that by `awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed)...'`

Comment: Subsequent calls to `rand()` will produce new values...it's only the same if you re-spawn awk.  But you're right!  We only need to call it once!  That'll speed it up quite a bit.

Comment: Its the re-spawning awk case I was talking about. It's unlikely you'd call it twice in 1 second but if you did you'd get the same output (unless you got lucky and crossed a seconds since the epoch change). Personally I usually don't care to handle that but since the OP seems pretty focused on randomness I thought I'd suggest `seed="$RANDOM"` if it matters.

Comment: Tried calling rand only once in BEGIN, and the output is heavily skewing to the beginning of the file.  Not sure why...

Comment: The +i in your loop should have taken care of it though. Let me try... I'll get back to you.

Comment: I get the same sort of results you do even if I change the seed from date+i to $RANDOM. I also get it if I call random 10 times in a loop in BEGIN. I can't imagine.... I'm running on cygwin FWIW (and my test loop takes 20-35 secs to complete vs your ~2 secs - I need a better laptop!)

Comment: I did `for i in $(seq 400); do awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed); r=rand(); d=int(10*r+1); print d}'; done | sort -n | uniq -c` and the distribution was fairly even so the problem isn't with the value `r` is getting but idk what it is.

Comment: It's the algorithm.  If you only randomize once, you'll get the first line half the time.  You need to roll the dice on each line for the algorithm to work.

Comment: Yeah you're right since the 2nd line and beyond only get matched when rand() outputs <= 0.5. I think you unfortunately also need to take the number of input lines into account. If the input file is 8 lines then the max value of 1/NR is 0.125 so every time rand() outputs any number in the range 0-0.125 the `out` will be the last line - hence the uptick at the last line of the sample output in the call-rand()-once case at least.

Comment: Did you see my comment/request at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765192/random-line-using-sed/55765592?noredirect=1#comment98212497_55768379?

Comment: @EdMorton I did not.  Running the scripts for timing now.

Answer (score 2):

```
var="Hi
i am a student
learning scripts"

mapfile -t array <<< "$var"      # create array from $var

echo "${array[$RANDOM % (${#array}+1)]}"
echo "${array[$RANDOM % (${#array}+1)]}"
```

Output (e.g.):

```
learning scripts
i am a student
```

---

See: `help mapfile`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the best solution for large input files:

```
awk -v seed="$RANDOM" -v max="$(wc -l < file)" 'BEGIN{srand(seed); n=int(rand()*max)+1} NR==n{print; exit}' file
```

as it uses standard UNIX tools, it's not restricted to files that are 32,769 lines long or less, it doesn't have any bias towards either end of the input, it'll produce different output even if called twice in 1 second, and it exits immediately after the target line is printed rather than continuing to the end of the input.

---

**Update:**

Having said the above, I have no explanation for why a script that calls rand() once per line and reads every line of input is about twice as fast as a script that calls rand() once and exits at the first matching line:

```
$ seq 100000 > file

$ time for i in $(seq 500); do
    awk -v seed="$RANDOM" -v max="$(wc -l < file)" 'BEGIN{srand(seed); n=int(rand()*max)+1} NR==n{print; exit}' file;
done > o3

real    1m0.712s
user    0m8.062s
sys     0m9.340s

$ time for i in $(seq 500); do
    awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} rand() < 1/NR{ out=$0 } END { print out}' file;
done > o4

real    0m29.950s
user    0m9.918s
sys     0m2.501s
```

They both produced very similar types of output:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++} END { for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' o3 | awk '{sum+=$2; max=(NR>1&&max>$2?max:$2); min=(NR>1&&min<$2?min:$2)} END{print NR, sum, min, max}'
498 500 1 2

$ awk '{a[$0]++} END { for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' o4 | awk '{sum+=$2; max=(NR>1&&max>$2?max:$2); min=(NR>1&&min<$2?min:$2)} END{print NR, sum, min, max}'
490 500 1 3
```

---

**Final Update:**

Turns out it was calling `wc` that (unexpectedly to me at least!) was taking most of the time. Here's the improvement when we take it out of the loop:

```
$ time { max=$(wc -l < file); for i in $(seq 500); do awk -v seed="$RANDOM" -v max="$max" 'BEGIN{srand(seed); n=int(rand()*max)+1} NR==n{print; exit}' file; done } > o3

real    0m24.556s
user    0m5.044s
sys     0m1.565s
```

so the solution where we call `wc` up front and `rand()` once is faster than calling `rand()` for every line as expected.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - would you mind checking the above and trying the timings to see if you get similar results?

Comment: On my laptop, the 2 run script (running wc -l) actually faster.  On only one run of each, 12.864 real time, vs 24.625.

Comment: But it occurs to me that we are perhaps missing the modern miracle of huge memory!   For this sort of thing these days it's probably easier to just read the whole file into memory and then select a line randomly in END!

Answer (score 0):

on bash shell, first initialize seed to # line cube or your choice

```
$ i=;while read a; do let i++;done<<<$var; let RANDOM=i*i*i

$ let l=$RANDOM%$i+1 ;echo -e $var |sed -En "$l p"
```

if move your data to `varfile`

```
$ echo -e $var >varfile
$ i=;while read a; do let i++;done<varfile; let RANDOM=i*i*i

$ let l=$RANDOM%$i+1 ;sed -En "$l p" varfile
```

put the last inside loop e.g. `for((c=0;c<9;c++)) { ;}`

Answer (score 0):

Using *GNU `sed`* and `bash`; no `wc` or `awk`:

```
f=input-file
sed -n $((RANDOM%($(sed = $f | sed '2~2d' | sed -n '$p')) + 1))p $f
```

Note: The three `sed`s in `$(...)` are an inefficient way to fake `wc -l < $f`.  Maybe there's a better way -- using only `sed` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Using `shuf`:

```
$ echo "$var" | shuf -n 1
```

Output:

```
Hi
```